# Is it possible for wcf data services to return metadata in json format?

Tags: json, wcf-data-services, odata

Is it possible for wcf data services to return metadata in json format?

The server return error 415 from this request ->

GET http://services.odata.org/V3/(S(plcxuejnllfvrrecpvqbehxz))/OData/OData.svc/$metadata HTTP/1.1
DataServiceVersion: 3.0;
Host: services.odata.org
Content-Length: 0
Accept: application/json;odata=verbose
Content-Type: application/json;odata=verbose

Comment: This might be useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3538131/is-there-a-wsdl-like-mechanism-for-json

Answer (score 0):

WCF can return json from methods, but service metadata is always xml (wsdl).

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing preventing the service from offering such capability, but OData currently doesn't define JSON format for the metadata endpoint response. So the server would have to come up with one (proprietary). This holds true for WCF Data Services, I don't know enough about plain WCF Services (and if there's a JSON version of WSDL).